# zf2 select columns from joined tables - how?

Tags: zend-framework2

I feel like I must me missing something very simple. It's a very simple task, all I want to do is get something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM lookup_items
JOIN lookup ON lookup_items.lookup_id = lookup.id
```

This returns all the columns for all the joined tables, in regular SQL. Here's my attempt in zf2:

```php
$select = new Select();

$select->from('lookup_items');
$select->join('lookup', 'lookup_items.lookup_id = lookup.id');
```

The result set only includes the columns in 'lookup_items'. I've tried various ways to get the 'lookup' columns, including:

```php
$select->columns(array('lookup_items.*', 'lookup.*'));
```

But they all just blow up. Surely there's a way to do this, and it's just so simple I'm missing it completely.

I thought a simple example would be avoid confusion, but here's more code:

```php
class LookupItemsTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
public function getList($resource)
{
    $system_name = str_replace('*', '%', strtoupper($resource));

    $joinTable = 'lookup';

    $select = new Select();

    $select->from($this->table);
    $select->join($joinTable, "{$this->table}.lookup_id = {$joinTable}.id");

    $where = array();
    $where[] = "{$this->table}.enabled is true";
    $where[] = "{$joinTable}.enabled is true";
    $where[] = "UPPER({$joinTable}.system_name) ilike '{$system_name}'";

    $select->where($where);

    $sort[] = 'sort_order ASC';
    $sort[] = 'value ASC';
    $select->order($sort);

    $rowset = $this->selectWith($select);

    return $rowset;
}
}
```

Where:

```php
$resource = $this->params()->fromRoute('resource', 'BUSINESS');
```

And $this->table is 'lookup_items'. Really all I want to do is get columns from both joined tables. I guess there's a zf2 way to just make a straight SQL statement without all the OO falderal, so I could just force it that way. But I'd rather work within the framework as much as possible.

Comment: What is the context of the code? Is it within a `TableGateway` class? If so are you setting an entity as a prototype for the result set? Can you post more code please.

Answer (score 7):

Just change this line

```
$select->join('lookup', 'lookup_items.lookup_id = lookup.id');
```

to

```
$select->join('lookup', 'lookup_items.lookup_id = lookup.id', array('lookupcol1', 'lookupcol2');
```

Comment: Additionally please read @"Al Fonce" ans below to get a clear picture of this problem

Answer (score 3):

Raj answer is the best one but it only works if you don't forget to add these fiels in your LookupItems model.

```php
class LookupItems
{
    // Your lookup_items fields here...
    ...
    // And the added lookup fields here, the ones you add in the array
    public $lookupcol1;
    public $lookupcol2;
```

And in the exchangeArray method :

```php
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
   // .... your fields, and the new ones
    $this->lookupcol1 = (! empty($data['lookupcol1'])) ? $data['lookupcol1'] : null;
    $this->lookupcol2 = (! empty($data['lookupcol2'])) ? $data['lookupcol2'] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Added this:

```
$select->columns(array('*'));
```

And then this near the end:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$rowset = $statement->execute();
```

This returns the expected result, with the caveat that now my rows are returned as associative arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you can create queries with join in zf2.

```
    $resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) {
            // omit the table name 
           //$select->from('foo');
            $select->join('users', "users.id foo.createdby", 'firstname', '');
            $select->order('id ASC');
           // echo $select->getSqlString();// to print your query
        });
    $entities = array();
    foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
        $entity = new Entity\Foo();
        $entity->setId($row->id)
            ->setFullname($row->fullname)
                    ->setCaseid($row->caseid)
                    ->setTestimonial($row->testimonial)
                    ->setSortorder($row->sortorder)
                    ->setActive($row->active)
                    ->setCreated($row->created)
                    ->setModified($row->modified)
                    ->setFirstname($row->firstname)
                    ->setCreatedby($row->createdby);
        $entities[] = $entity;
    }

    return $entities;
```